# How to remove empty directories from a tarball in-place

Tags: bash, shell, gnu, tar

I extracted a layer from a docker image which archived in a file called layer.tar. I want to remove empty directories from it.

I don't want to unpack then repack files in that archive, I want to keep the original info, so I want to do it in-place.

I know how to delete files from tar but I don't know any simple method to delete empty directories in-place.

Comment: tar isn't a format generally built with support for in-place modifications of any kind in mind. There *are* archive formats built with that intent -- `zip` is one of them -- but it's something that has to be an explicit design consideration (if you really mean "in-place" in a sense that excludes `sed -i`-style "write a new file, rename it over the old one, and *pretend* we did an in-place edit" operations).

Comment: What means `in-place`? What is the `original info` in a tar archive? Tar is just a format to compress files and only files, there are no "hidden" original info in it.

Comment: @KamilCuk, "in-place" in this context means "by editing the file, not recreating it or generating a new/derivative one". I'm assuming the OP is referring to not wanting to disturb timestamps or other metadata -- as can happen if doing an unpack/repack as a user without privileges to `chown`, for example.

Comment: @haolun, ...another question -- how strongly do you need to do this in shell? There's a Python `tarfile` library that would let you create a file with identical metadata but some content left out easily enough.

Answer (score 1):

Let's create a archive t.tar with `a/b/c/` and `a/b/c/d/` empty directories:

```
mkdir -p dir
cd dir
mkdir -p a/b/c/d
mkdir -p 1/2/3/4
touch a/fil_ea a/b/file_ab # directory a/b/c and a/b/c/d are empty
touch 1/2/3/file_123 1/2/3/4/file_1234 # directories 1/2/3/4 not empty
tar cf ../t.tar a 1
cd ..
```

Using `tar tf` and some filtering we can extract the directories and files in a tar archive. Then for each directory in `tmpdirs` we can check if it has any files in `tmpfiles` with a simple grep and then remove those directories using `--delete` tar option:

```
tar tf t.tar | tee >(grep '/$' > tmpdirs) | grep -v '/$' > tmpfiles
cat tmpdirs | xargs -n1 -- sh -c 'grep -q "$1" tmpfiles || echo "$1"' -- \
  | tac \
  | xargs -- tar --delete -f t.tar
```

Not that tac is a bit unneeded, but the files where sorted alphabetically in tar, so when tar removes the directory `a/b/c/` with all subdirectories first and then tries to remove `a/b/c/d/` directory it fails with an `Not found in archive` in error. `tac` is a cheap way to fix that, so tar first removes `a/b/c/d/` and then `a/b/c/`.